# How to store an array of objects of a particular class in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Suppose I have a Javascript class defined this way:

```
class TmpTestResult {
        constructor(id, title, testresult, tags, subsystem, info){
           this.ID = id;
           this.Title = title;
           this.TestResult = testresult;
           this.Tags = tags;
           this.Subystem = subsystem;
           this.Info = info;
}
```

How do I go about storing an array of TmpTestResults in Javascript?

(I'm so used to strongly typed c#, that I am at a loss as to how to do this.)

My sample data looks like this:

```
function GetFakeData() {
        var fakeTestResultArray = {
            "jsonData": "",
            "listResults": [{
                "MyViewName": "Test View",
                "ID": "10233",
                "Title": "Verify the Production data is working.",
                "TestResult": "Pass",
                "Tags": "ATAB, Production, MOCK",
                "Subsystem": "TEST",
                "Info": "OK : OK"
            },
            {
                "MyViewName": "Test View",
                "ID": "54875",
                "Title": "Verify the Production data is working one more time.",
                "TestResult": "Pass",
                "Tags": "ATAB, Production, MOCK",
                "Subsystem": "TEST",
                "Info": "OK : OK"
            },
            {
                "MyViewName": "Test View",
                "ID": "87541",
                "Title": "Verify the Production data is working for a third.",
                "TestResult": "Pass",
                "Tags": "ATAB, Production, MOCK",
                "Subsystem": "TEST",
                "Info": "OK : OK"
                }],
            "MyViewName": "TEST Tests",
            "ErrorInfo": "none",
            "Count" : 0
        }
```

Comment: If you're so used to strong-typing, I would suggest to use TypeScript. Makes the flow from backend to frontend much smoother.

Comment: How would you do this in C# ?

Comment: Strongly recommend adopting standard JavaScript naming conventions, which differ from C#'s standard naming conventions (at least when anyone else is going to need to read the code)...

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Can you provide a link to the naming convention standard you would use?

Comment: @SuLlewellyn - Naming in JavaScript is really simple. :-) Variables, parameters, properties, non-constructor functions, and methods all start with a lower-case letter and use camelCase. Constructor functions (which is what you're specifying after `class`) start with an upper-case letter and use CamelCase. Some people write symbolic constants (like the number of milliseconds in a day) in ALL_CAPS_WITH_UNDERSCORES. Others don't. Essentially, like C# except for a lower initial letter (except for constructor function/class names).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.map` and return the `TmpTestResult` objects like

```
fakeTestResultArray.listResults.map(o => new TmpTestResult(o.ID, o.Title, o.TestResult, o.Tags, o.Subsystem, o.Info));
```

Here is snippet

```js
class TmpTestResult {
    constructor(id, title, testresult, tags, subsystem, info) {
        this.ID = id;
        this.Title = title;
        this.TestResult = testresult;
        this.Tags = tags;
        this.Subystem = subsystem;
        this.Info = info;
    }
}
var fakeTestResultArray = {
    "jsonData": "",
    "listResults": [{
            "MyViewName": "Test View",
            "ID": "10233",
            "Title": "Verify the Production data is working.",
            "TestResult": "Pass",
            "Tags": "ATAB, Production, MOCK",
            "Subsystem": "TEST",
            "Info": "OK : OK"
        },
        {
            "MyViewName": "Test View",
            "ID": "54875",
            "Title": "Verify the Production data is working one more time.",
            "TestResult": "Pass",
            "Tags": "ATAB, Production, MOCK",
            "Subsystem": "TEST",
            "Info": "OK : OK"
        },
        {
            "MyViewName": "Test View",
            "ID": "87541",
            "Title": "Verify the Production data is working for a third.",
            "TestResult": "Pass",
            "Tags": "ATAB, Production, MOCK",
            "Subsystem": "TEST",
            "Info": "OK : OK"
        }
    ],
    "MyViewName": "TEST Tests",
    "ErrorInfo": "none",
    "Count": 0
}



var res = fakeTestResultArray.listResults.map(o => new TmpTestResult(o.ID, o.Title, o.TestResult, o.Tags, o.Subsystem, o.Info));

console.log(res)
```

Comment: Would the Javascript Set be more appropriate for this kind of problem?

Comment: The [**`Set`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) object lets you store unique values of any type. There is no such need of using `set` in this case

Comment: Thank you for setting me straight! I think map is good solution for these reasons:
- you don't have to write loops,
- you don't have to access the original array or the index position if you don't want to
- A new array is produced.
Caveats seem to be:
- Always return something from your mapping function. (JS provides a default return undefined)
- If the input array elements are objects or arrays, and you include them in the output array, then Javascript will still allow the original elements to be accessed.

Answer (score 1):

You just use a standard array and call your constructor:

```
function GetFakeData() {
    var fakeTestResultArray = {
        "jsonData": "",
        "listResults": [
            new TmpTestResult(
                "10233", 
                "Verify the Production data is working.",
                "Pass",
                "ATAB, Production, MOCK",
                "TEST",
                "OK : OK"
            ),
            new TmpTestResult(/*...*/),
            new TmpTestResult(/*...*/),
            new TmpTestResult(/*...*/),
        ],
        "MyViewName": "TEST Tests",
        "ErrorInfo": "none",
        "Count" : 0
    }
```

You might consider having the constructor accept an object (perhaps optionally), so you can use literal notation for those:

```
class TmpTestResult {
    constructor(id, title, testresult, tags, subsystem, info){
       if (typeof id === "object") {
           Object.assign(this, id);
       } else {
           this.ID = id;
           this.Title = title;
           this.TestResult = testresult;
           this.Tags = tags;
           this.Subystem = subsystem;
           this.Info = info;
       }
}
```

Then

```
function GetFakeData() {
    var fakeTestResultArray = {
        "jsonData": "",
        "listResults": [
            new TmpTestResult({
                "MyViewName": "Test View",
                "ID": "10233",
                "Title": "Verify the Production data is working.",
                "TestResult": "Pass",
                "Tags": "ATAB, Production, MOCK",
                "Subsystem": "TEST",
                "Info": "OK : OK"
            }),
            new TmpTestResult({
                // ...
            }),
            // ...
```

JavaScript doesn't have C#'s property-assignment-during-construction thing (whatever it's called) where you can do `new TmpTestResult { ID = "..."`... But optionally accepting an object is close.

Comment: Having to use this functionality in an MVC app, I think this is more along the lines I'd be looking for to mock this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript everything is a primitive type such as string or number, or array [ ]  or object { }.
Store your data in an array of objects which can have nested objects too.
Basically, the fakeTestResultArray is already doing a good job.

Now you should look for a database which can keep you JSON objects. Something like MongoDB.

Comment: That is not true. The important distinction is that **values** have types. Variables, on the other hand, do not (whereas in statically-typed languages, they do). There is a `typeof` operator for a reason.

Comment: Also, there is no such thing as a "list []" type. It's called an array, and the type is still an `Object`

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I edited the parts that were not correct. but the rest still is the same.